# Finding the source of large idle within Chrome dev tools

Tags: google-chrome, google-chrome-devtools, profiler

I'm trying to find the source of some "idle" time within a certain page I'm accessing on our system. The problem is weird though to me, as I cant tell the reason for the delay. I'm running this in a single instance of chrome, no other tabs or anything.

The initial load time looks like this:
[image]

So it takes a while. But if I refresh this page within 7-8 seconds it will come back really quickly.

[image]

I initially though it was a system process on our end and ran Yii's profiler which came back with:

[image]

So, it seemed to be a non "system" issue, so went to Chrome's dev tools and the profile comes back with this:

[image]

I've read the other question [What causes Chrome Timeline Frame to have so much empty white space](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12302286/what-causes-chrome-timeline-frame-to-have-so-much-empty-white-space) also.

I'm trying to understanding if it's possible to identify the problem at all and why the page is rendered quickly if the page is refreshed after a few seconds of loading and why it takes so long if the refesh is called after 7-8 seconds of the initial load?

**nb** Some of the times might not match up as I've run the various profilers a few times. So they might apply to different page refreshes. But you can see the general trend :)

Comment: Can you reproduce the issue on other machines?

Comment: @KayceBasques Yes a coworker actually pointed it out to me on his machine and our various test and production machines

Comment: Is it actually working, or was it just sitting for 15 seconds?

Comment: @MikeDunlavey chrome says it's working. The icon is spinning. It's a fairly small SQL pull. The Yii profiler just shows this huge space in between DB calls. But they are all around 1-2ms? I'm really not sure of the source of this "lag". So was hoping for some ideas or further things I could do to help find out where this is

Comment: @Jonnny: I'm no expert on this particular profiler, but I/O-bound programs tend to look like that - they can spend a large fraction of their time just waiting. The question is - what are they waiting for? For that, I (and others) use [*stackshots*](http://stackoverflow.com/a/378024/23771).